# Android - Cannot get the URI from the anonymously called method

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am facing the problem I cannot resolve for a week. So, what I am trying to do, is to save an image into internal memory, get back its URI and save it to the SQLite DB. My problem is that I cannot get the URI from anonymously called method "done". I cannot rewrite it, since I use Parse API to convert ParseFile into Image. Code is below:

```
public class DataFetch extends IntentService {

public final String LOG_TAG = DataFetch.class.getSimpleName();
private TestUri mImageUri;

public DataFetch() {
    super("UriTest");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Set up background task here
    try {
        // Locate the class table named "Test_Images" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryTest = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Test_Images");
        List<ParseObject> testData = queryTest.find();

        //Insert the new test information into the database
        Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(testData.size());

        for(ParseObject object : testData) {
            // Create a ContentValues object to hold data which would be added to DB.
            final ContentValues testDataValues = new ContentValues();
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile)object.get("image");
            final String imageName = object.getString("name");

            //Log.i("data_fetch","before inner class: "+mImageUri.getUri());
            if(image != null){
                mImageUri = new TestUri();
                image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Bitmap straight after creation: "+bitmap);
                            if(bitmap != null){
                                //Set image of the event in place
                                mImageUri.setUri(saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, imageName));
                                Log.i("data_fetch", "inner class: " + mImageUri.getUri());
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Bitmap straight after processing: " + bitmap + " and its length is " + data.length);
                            }
                            else {
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file null?");
                                mImageUri.setUri("nothing_here");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ParseFile ParseException: " + e.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ParseFile is null");
            }
            Log.i("data_fetch","after inner class: "+mImageUri.getUri());

            // Insert the name and id of the data.
            testDataValues.put(DataTestContract.TestFieldEntry.COL_NAME, imageName);
            Log.i("data_fetch", "name: " + object.getString("name"));
            testDataValues.put(DataTestContract.TestFieldEntry.COL_CAT, object.getString("Id"));
            Log.i("data_fetch", "id: " + object.getString("Id"));
            // Insert image URI into ContentValues object.
            testDataValues.put(DataTestContract.TestFieldEntry.COL_URI, mImageUri.getUri());
            Log.i("data_fetch","image uri: "+mImageUri.getUri());
            cVVector.add(testDataValues);
        }
        //Add test data to database
        int inserted = 0;
        int deleted = 0;
        // add to database
        if (cVVector.size() > 0) {
            ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[cVVector.size()];
            cVVector.toArray(cvArray);
            for(int i=0;i<cvArray.length;++i){
                Log.i("data_fetch","data passed to cvArray: "+cVVector.get(i));
                Log.i("data_fetch", "data to be inserted: " + cvArray[i]);
            }
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().bulkInsert(DataTestContract.TestFieldEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
            //Delete old data from DB

        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Sync Complete. " + cVVector.size() + " Inserted. Deleted:"+deleted);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image, String name) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    name.trim();
    File mypath=new File(directory, name+".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mypath.getAbsolutePath();
}

public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context, DataFetch.class);
        context.startService(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: up up up up up up up!

Comment: up up up up up up up!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to implement it.

```
var resizeImageKey = require('cloud/resize-image-key');
var ImageMetadata = Parse.Object.extend("ImageMetadata");

var NORMAL_WIDTH = 612;
var SMALL_WIDTH = 110;

// Resize image into various sizes before saving
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Image", function(req, res) {
  var original = req.object.get('sizeOriginal');

  Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
    // Create an image metadata object on creation
    if (req.object.isNew()) {
      var im = new ImageMetadata;
      im.set("views", 0);
      return im.save();    
    }
  }).then(function(im) {
    // Set the metadata object relationship
    if (im) {
      req.object.set("imageMetadata", im);
    }

    if (!original) {
      return Parse.Promise.error("No original sized image file set.");
    }

    if (!req.object.dirty("sizeOriginal")) {
      // The original isn't being modified.
      return Parse.Promise.as();
    }

    // Don't set blank titles
    if (req.object.get("title").length === 0) {
      req.object.unset("title");
    }

    // Resize to a normal "show" page image size  
    return resizeImageKey({
      object: req.object,
      fromKey: "sizeOriginal",
      toKey: "sizeNormal",
      width: NORMAL_WIDTH
    })
  }).then(function() {
    // Resize to a smaller size for thumbnails
    return resizeImageKey({
      object: req.object,
      fromKey: "sizeOriginal",
      toKey: "sizeSmall",
      width: SMALL_WIDTH,
      crop: true
    });
  }).then(function(result) {
    res.success();
  }, function(error) {
    res.error(error);
  });
});

// Does all the work to update metadata about an image upon a view
Parse.Cloud.define("viewImage", function(request, response) {
  // Use the master key to prevent clients from tampering with view count
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var object = new ImageMetadata;
  object.id = request.params.metadataId;

  object.increment("views");
  object.save().then(function() {
    response.success();
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: i suppose your way does work, but it would be better to see code in Java, rather then different language. Also it requires to write extra lines of code and don't see how it solve my issue.